# Calling derived class function without marking it as virtual from a class in middle in multi-level inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I'm thinking that it could be a repeat question but I tried reading almost all the related posts and none of them were specific to what I'm looking for.

OK, So I understand that you cannot call a function in derived class from a base class pointer unless it is marked virtual. Like in reference program 1, it cannot call B class' WhichClass() if WhichClass() is not marked virtual.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
  public:
  const char* WhichClass(){return "A";}
};
class B:public A
{
  public:
  const char* WhichClass(){return "B";}
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  A &a = b;
  cout<<"In class "<<a.WhichClass();
  return 0;
}
```

If I mark it as virtual then it calls the function of the most derived class from the base class. Now suppose if I add another class C inheriting from B (as shown in program 2), and if WhichClass() is not marked as virtual in the class B, then how can base reference (&a) call WhichClass() function in Class C? Also with class B reference (&b), how can it call WhichClass() in C when it is not even marked as virtual in class B as per what we observed in program 1?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
  public:
  virtual const char* WhichClass(){return "A";}
};
class B:public A 
{
  public:
  const char* WhichClass(){return "B";}
};
class C:public B
{
  public:
  const char* WhichClass() { return "C";}
};
int main()
{
  C c;
  A &a = c;
  B &b = c;

  cout<<"In class " << a.WhichClass() << endl;
  cout<<"In class " << b.WhichClass() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you make a method a virtual in base class and create a base class pointer point to any derived class, then in that case it calls the most derived class function.
In your case you have,

```
A &a = c;
```

here a pointer of base class A is pointing to class C, so when you call the WhichClass() method then method of class C is called.

```
B &b = c;
```

even here also when you call a function using base class pointer, the function of most derived class is called based on which class you are pointing. In this case pointer of class B is pointing to object of class C, so WhichClass() method of class C will be called.
For more details, please check this,[polymorphism](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm)

Comment: Thanks, just confirming on the first case. But in the 2nd one, function is not marked as virtual, how did it know that it should be calling class C's WhichClass()? IMO, the v-table entry in Class B point to B::WhichClass() because it is not virtual. no?

Comment: but B is inheriting from A where the function is marked as virtual so A has vtable entry for its virtual function, when A is inherited by any other class another vtable is created for that class which makes the derive class function virtual..

Answer (score 2):

1. In a class chain, If you declare some function in base class as `virtual` all the bellow level derived class functions with same definition automatically will be `virtual`.
2. The scene behind this function selection according to overriding, done by concept call `virtual table`. So if you curious about, read [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/)
3. In C++ 11 you can use `final` keyword to stop overriding at some level. (eg: if you want to avoid class 'C' to override class 'B's `WhichClass` function). check [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)